Ethers.js 6.11: Contract doesn't have any methods or attributes after I create it
I have a contract deployed on sepolia test net (seen with Etherscan) that I'm trying to interact with from a vue app. I'm using Ethers.js 6.11 to attempt to create a contract connection through MetaMask (which I'm sure is also connected to Sepolia).
  async mounted () { 
if(window.ethereum)
{
  this.provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  this.accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
  this.contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, ABI.abi, this.provider)
  console.log(this.contract); //dumps out a huge object
  console.log(this.contract.address); //this comes back 'undefined'
  console.log(await this.contract.contractOwner()) //this breaks

}
else
{
  console.log("MetaMask not detected")
}}

The MetaMask connection seems to be fine since it asks me to approve the connection and I can read my provider account.
According to the Ethers 6.11 documentation, there should be attributes of the contract that I can read, and the functions I can execute. But, when I attempt to read attributes such as the address (an example they use in the docs), it comes back with undefined. When I attempt to run the function to read a public variable of the contract, address payable public contractOwner;, it just breaks like this.
_assertClassBrand@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/assertClassBrand.js:7:9
call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/providers/abstract-provider.js:746:171
asyncstaticCallResult@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:284:29
asyncstaticCall@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:252:26
method@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/contract/contract.js:297:20
mounted@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:31:39
async*createHook/</<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2674:90
callWithErrorHandling@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:328:19
callWithAsyncErrorHandling@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:335:38
injectHook/hook.__weh@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2656:45
flushPostFlushCbs@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:487:41
render@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5853:7
mount@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3657:19
createApp/app.mount@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1702:24
@webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:6:98
./src/main.js@http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:41:1
webpack_require@http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:166:32
webpack_exports<@http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1282:109
webpack_require.O@http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:208:23
@http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1283:53
@http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1285:12
I'm guessing it's just complaining that the function doesn't exist. I've double checked that the ABI looks correct. If I just log out the this.contract object, I can see that it contains a bunch of fragments that have names of all the functions and stuff, so it looks like the contract is at least partially being created. Any insight on why I can't use the contract for anything would be helpful. It's probably something silly, but I've been spinning on this for hours.

Can you share the contract address and ABI ?
